# Simple HTML App with NGNIX Docker container doesn't run on Railway.app - Application failed to respond (error-503)

Tags: docker, deployment

I have a simple HTML application. Everything works fine locally. Here is my Dockerfile, which is in the same folder and is also found by Railway.

Response from Railway.app:

```
  <h1 class="error-404">Nothing here... yet</h1>
  <h1 class="error-503">Application failed to respond</h1>
```

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
# Use the official nginx base image from Docker Hub
FROM nginx

# Copy the contents of the current directory to the specified directory in the container
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I also tried with this version (-> same results):

```
# Use the official nginx base image from Docker Hub
FROM nginx

# Copy the contents of the current directory to the specified directory in the container
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx when the container has provisioned. 
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is my project:

```
ls
app.html  assets  Dockerfile  favicon.ico  index.html  README.md
```

Build logs from Railway:

```
=========================
Using Detected Dockerfile
=========================
context: 13a5a...d67dbac
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 234B done
 
#1 DONE 0.2s
 
#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
 
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.2s
 
#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:latest
 
#3 DONE 0.8s
 
 
#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:af296b...092305
#4 DONE 0.0s
 
#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 3.58MB 0.0s done
 
#5 DONE 0.2s
 
#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:af296b1...092305
#4 CACHED
 
#6 [2/2] COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
 
#6 DONE 0.1s
 
#7 exporting to image
#7 exporting layers 0.0s done
#7 writing image sha256:e7fd80a...edb6b done
#7 naming to us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/railway-infra/railway-docker-users/project/8691...eefe3/service/17ba0e...d8f73:7865...df2682 0.0s done
#7 DONE 0.1s
 
Build time: 1.54 seconds
 
================
Publishing Image
================
The push refers to repository [us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/railway-infra/railway-docker-users/project/8691...efe3/service/17ba...8f73]
Preparing  f0b9a7bbdced
Preparing  4fd834341303
Preparing  5e099cf3f3c8
Preparing  7daac92f43be
Preparing  e60266289ce4
Preparing  4b8862fe7056
Preparing  8cbe4b54fa88
Waiting  4b8862fe7056
Waiting  8cbe4b54fa88
Layer already exists  4fd834341303
Pushing [>                                                  ]  53.39kB/3.58MB f0b9a7bbdced
Layer already exists  e60266289ce4
Layer already exists  5e099cf3f3c8
Layer already exists  7daac92f43be
Layer already exists  4b8862fe7056
Layer already exists  8cbe4b54fa88
Pushing [=========================>                         ]  1.837MB/3.58MB f0b9a7bbdced
Pushing [==================================================>]  3.611MB f0b9a7bbdced
Pushed  f0b9a7bbdced
7865993f...bdf2682: digest: sha256:683c0...fe44 size: 1782
 
Publish time: 0.64 seconds
```

Deploy log:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.0
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.19.0-22-cloud-amd64
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/05/27 17:18:00 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I have already restarted, rebuilt and even completely deleted the project from Railway.app and uploaded it again from GitHub and then auto-generated a new domain.
Does Dockerfile need additional commands or does Railway.app need to set something in the project?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the error of the browser?

Comment: @Balint done. Maybe Railway does not allow the use of nginx or uses some specific configurations? Maybe the project needs to have a specific folder?

Comment: Does Railapp redirect the traffic in the port 80?

Comment: @Balint I don't see where to explicitly enable port 80 for Railways under settings. I assume that it is active by default.

Comment: @Balint I added "PORT" with the value 80 as a variable for my project in Railway and it suddenly worked! Thank you, I've been sitting on this problem for many hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Balint, I finally found the solution. I wrongly assumed that port 80 is active by default. You have to create a project variable "PORT" with the value "80". Apparently Railway searches for this variable in the project and without this variable the port is not exposed.

Comment: Thank you for your self-answer. This [Railway doc](https://docs.railway.app/deploy/exposing-your-app) explains it: "**PORT** is a Railway-provided environment variable, you can manually override it by adding PORT to your projects variables page". Here's also a [list of other predefined variables](https://docs.railway.app/develop/variables#railway-provided-variables).